# Concatenate multiple range adaptors into one single ranges in C++20

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3, std-ranges

Consider the following case:

```
std::vector<int> v{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
// 0 1 2 3 4 5
auto rng1 = std::views::all(v);
// 5 4 3 2 1 0
auto rng2 = std::views::reverse(v);
// 4 2 0
auto rng3 = std::views::filter(rng2, [](int x){return x % 2 == 0;});
```

Is there a elegant way to concatenate those three adaptors into one single view like this:

```
// 0 1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 1 0 4 2 0
auto final_rng = std::views::concat(rng1, rng2, rng3);
```

It seems impossible since `rng1`, `rng2`, and `rng3`'s are very different types.

Can someone give an alternative solution? thanks.

Comment: It's certainly possible. I don't see it in the standard library, but this would be `my_concat<type of rng1, type of rng2, type of rng3>`, whose iterators are basically a `variant<rng1::iter, rng2::iter, rng3::iter>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, what you wrote just in a different namespace - there's no concat in the Standard Library but there is one in [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/):

```
auto final_rng = ranges::views::concat(rng1, rng2, rng3);
```

The fact that the ranges are different types doesn't pose a problem. You just have an iterator that's built up of a variant of the underlying iterators of the ranges. The important part is that the value type of the ranges is the same - and here it is, so that's totally fine.

Comment: Why isn't it in the std ranges too?

Comment: Probably just time limitations. I expect the concatenation of different ranges can get quite complicated depending on which types of access/iteration they support. Implementing a working version is quite different from a formally correct definition that can then be implemented performantly.

Comment: I don't see a views::concat() in the standard neither in C++20 nor in C++23. Is this a major missing feature or is there another easy way to achieve this ?

Comment: Seems like this is planned for C++26 https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/1204

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a concat() in the standard coming with C++23 2/3. Check out the spec:
https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2214r0.html

Comment: Good to see plans for it to be added. It's worth noting that the current C++23 draft (N4928) does not yet contain a concat (it would be a range factory in 26.6 if it were there).